# Cannot call method 'SaveScreenshot' of undefined - cordova

Tags: cordova, plugins, undefined, screenshot

Hi this is my first post but I've been trying to use the Screenshot plugin from here:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/88a57e1c232f604f73be5bd82868d711ac235424/Android/Screenshot

And I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'SaveScreenshot' of undefined at file ...
And I really dont know why it's throwing me an error!! Any help will be welcome

Here is the JS that is calling the method:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        // PhoneGap is ready
        //
     function onDeviceReady() {
        $('#saveBtn').click(function(){
            window.plugins.Screenshot.saveScreenshot();
        }); 
  }
```

And here is the html for the button

```
<button id="saveBtn">Save</button><br>
```

I have sourced the Screenshot.js file and everything

EDIT:  I am using Cordova 2.0.0 if that helps and I'm using the plugin Screenshot that was coded for the same version of Cordova

Comment: Does this error happen when the button is pressed or before the button is even touched?

Comment: when the button is pressed

Comment: try: `window.plugins.screenshot.saveScreenshot()`

Comment: No doesn't work it just gave me a list of a lot more errors

Comment: What were those errors?  Looking at the source code for Screenshot.js, `windows.plugins.screenshot` appears to be all lower case: `if (!window.plugins.screenshot) {
    window.plugins.screenshot = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/screenshot");
}`

Comment: Sorry it actually worked the second time!! I think the emulator was having a problem the first time! Thank you so so much!!! and it was such an easy mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
window.plugins.screenshot.saveScreenshot();
```

From the source code `windows.plugins.screenshot` appears to be in all lower case characters:

```
if (!window.plugins.screenshot) { 
    window.plugins.screenshot = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/screenshot");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem. Here I am explaining the problem causes for me. Goto your plugin config.xml and see whether the directory paths are correct or not.

```
<js-module src="www/hello.js" name="hello">
<clobbers target="cordova.plugins.hello" />
```

```
<config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
  <feature name="Hello">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.example.hello.Hello"/>
  </feature>
</config-file>

<source-file src="src/android/Hello.java" target-dir="src/com/example/hello"/>
```

Be specific about paths. Sometimes it kills our time .